# homotopic to a constant map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Prove that any continuous map $f\colon RP^3\to S^1$ is homotopic to a constant map?

How to prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh?  Any constant map is clearly continuous and homotopic to a constant map.  Maybe you mean *not* homotopic to a constant map?

Comment: I edited your question by a missing verb "is", in order to fix the grammar and to say what  I think you intended to ask. If I'm wrong then feel free to rever the edit.

Comment: A hint: use [arbitrary map lifting lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145068/591889) w.r.t. the cover $\Bbb R\ni t\longmapsto \exp(2\pi it)\in \Bbb S^1$ with [$\pi_1(\Bbb RP^3)=\Bbb Z_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766211/fundamental-group-of-mathbbrpn). Define a homotopy between the lift and constant map$(\Bbb R$ is contractible$)$, and then compose the above covering with this homotopy.

Comment: You might also know that the homotopy classes of maps from a CW-complex $X$ to $S^1$ are in bijection with $H^1(X;\mathbb Z)$ which is $0$ in your case. This is a theorem of Hopf, and can be seen as a particular case of $H^1$ being a functor representable by Eilenberg-MacLane spaces

Comment: @User873110 Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost: Because the question deserves to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Since [$\pi_1(\Bbb RP^3)=\Bbb Z_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766211/fundamental-group-of-mathbbrpn) and $\pi_1(\Bbb S^1)=\Bbb Z$ the induced group homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(\Bbb RP^3)\to \pi_1(\Bbb S^1)$ is the zero homomorphism.

Hence, by the [arbitrary map lifting lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4019296/591889) we can lift the map $f$ w.r.t the covering $\Bbb R\ni t\longmapsto \exp(2\pi it)\in \Bbb S^1$. That is there is a map $\widetilde f:\Bbb RP^3\to \Bbb R$ with $\exp\big(2\pi i\widetilde f(x)\big)=f(x)$.

*Note that to lift a map, we must ensure that the domain of the map is locally path-connected and connected. But here we are dealing with connected manifolds, so we do not need to worry.*

Now, consider the homotopy $H:\Bbb RP^3\times [0,1]\ni (x,t)\longmapsto \exp\big(2\pi i (1-t)\widetilde f(x)\big)\in \Bbb S^1$.